# Upgrade CentOS 5.2 to 5.3 -- but not 5.4

Tags: linux, centos

Server currently running CentOS 5.2. Developers tell me they'd like the machine upgrade to CentOS 5.3 -- but not all the way to CentOS 5.4, as they haven't tested with 5.4 yet.

I'm pretty sure a yum upgrade will put me at 5.4, as a yum check-update shows all sorts of 5.4 packages.

So how do I move up to 5.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

work around for such scenario you can download centos 5.3 dvd, and create local repo ans then you run the yum upgrade

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to run into this problem repeatedly and you want better long-term control over rolling packages out over multiple environments (development, staging, production), you should look into setting yourself up a [Spacewalk][1] server, and then you'll be able to create frozen-in-time channels that correspond to particular releases that you can attach/upgrade servers to.

[1]: http://www.redhat.com/spacewalk/ Spacewalk

Answer (score 1):

Just point it directly at the dvd to upgrade.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-linux-install-packages-from-dvd-using-yum/